# Countifs by consider dates range

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I have a formula which is like this

=COUNTIFS('sheet1 '!W:W,">0",'sheet1 '!A:A,"Truck")

which is count all data in column W (sheet1) larger than 0, which are called Truck in column A.

Now, I want this formula to read the same information but by consider a range of dates in between 1st of October to 15th (I have dates in Column B).
Any input is greatly appreciate.
Thanks

Comment: Did you mean to tag this [google-spreadsheets]?

Answer (score 1):

If you’re talking about Excel, the formula is

```
=COUNTIFS(W:W,">0", A:A,"Truck", B:B,">10/1/2017", B:B,"<10/15/2017")
```

You may want to change the `>` and `<` to `>=` and `<=`,
depending on whether you want to include Oct 1 and Oct 15
in your “between” range. 
Illustration:

[image: Excel spreadsheet illustrating the above formula]

Only row 7 is counted.

If you’re talking about Google spreadsheets, the above might also work,
but I don’t know.

---

And, of course,
if you normally write dates as `dd/mm/yyyy`,
then you should use `1/10/2017` and `15/10/2017`.

Comment: *As usual* with Excel formulas, the argument separator depends on your region / localization settings.  Some people will need to use semicolons (`;`) instead of commas (`,`) in the formula.  (These may be the same people who write dates as dd/mm/yyyy.)